# I want to prove that a topological space is a category with elements as objects and homotopy equivalence classes of paths as morphisms.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I want to prove that a topological space $(X,T)$ is a category. Here $X$ is a the underlying set and $T$ a topology on $X$.

1) Let the objects be the elements of $X$.

2) For each $x,y \in X$ the morphisms from $x$ to $y$ consists of all homotopy equivalence classes of paths with starting point $x$ and end point $y$.

3) For each $x \in X$ we define $\text{Id}_x$ to be the equivalence class of the constant path.

4) Let $x,y,z \in X$ and let $[f] : x \rightarrow y$ and $[g]: \rightarrow z$. We define the compostion of $[f]$ and $[g]$ by $[f] \circ [g] = [f * g]$. Where $(f * g)(t) = \begin{cases} 
f(2t) \quad 0 \le t \le 1/2\\
g(2t-1) \quad 1/2 \le t \le 1\\
\end{cases}$
And the $[ \cdot ]$ denotes taking the homotopy equivalence class.

C1) That the composition is associative.
We have $((f*g)*h)(t) = \begin{cases}
f(4t) \quad 0 \le t \le 1/4 \\
g(4t - 1) \quad 1/4 \le t \le 1/2\\
h(2t - 1) \quad 1/2 \le t \le 1
\end{cases}$
and 
$
(f*(g*h))(t) = \begin{cases} 
f(2t) \quad 0 \le t \le 1/2\\
g(4t - 2) \quad 1/2 \le t \le 3/4\\
h(4t - 3) \quad 3/4 \le t \le 1
\end{cases}
$.

And the homotopy is given by
H(t,s) = \begin{cases} 
f(4t/(s+1)) \quad 0 \le t \le (s+1)/4\\
g(4t - 1 -s) \quad (s+1)/4 \le t \le (s + 2)/4\\
h((4t -2 -s)/(2 -s)) \quad (s+2)/4 \le t \le 1.
\end{cases}
From this we deduce that the composition is associative.

C2) $\text{Id}_x \circ [f] = [f]$. Let $x,y \in X$ and $[f]:x\rightarrow y$. We define the following homotopy
$K(t,s) = \begin{cases}
x \quad 0 \le t \le (1-s)/2\\
f((2t+s-1)/(s+1))\quad (1-s)/2 \le t \le 1.
\end{cases}$

The map $K$ is continuous since $f$ and it is a composition of continuous functions. The homotopy gives us that $\text{Id}_x \circ [f] = [f]$. Similarly we can show that $[f] \circ \text{Id}_x = [f]$.

Furthermore we can show that each morphism has an inverse.
$f^{-1}(t) = f(1-t)$.
Were we use the homotopy
$
L(t,s) = \begin{cases} 
f(2ts) \quad 0 \le t \le 1/2\\
f(2s - 2ts) \quad 1/2 \le t \le 1.
\end{cases}
$

The result that all the homotopy equivalence classes of loops from a fixed point form a group is now an instance of the result in category that states that:
for any object $x$ we have that $\text{Aut}(x)$ is a group.

Is my prove correct?

Comment: Cannot withhold myself from providing a link to [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf) of Ronnie Brown. In chapter $6$ the fundamental groupoid (i.e. category where every arrow is invertible) based on a topological space is constructed.

Comment: What do you mean "is" a category? Non-homeomorphic topological spaces such as $\Bbb Q$ with standard topology vs. discrete topology lead to exectly the same category under your construction.

Comment: The identity should be the class of the constant map, not the constant map itself.

Comment: This category, the "fundamental groupoid" of $X$, is also described in Spanier's book "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: @Randall fixed it, thanks

Comment: Adding to @HagenvonEitzen 's comment, usually the set of arrows of a category is more important than the set of objects (in the sense that objects can be recovered from arrows and composition but not the converse). I for one do like to see topological spaces as categories, but rather as unit groupoids.

Comment: This is a rather technical and boring argument to check if you have no specific question about it. At a glance it looks lonely to be correct.